# ColdFusion MX 7 Licensing Issue?

Tags: licensing, coldfusion

I have a site running ColdFusion MX 7 which I know nothing about, but it was all working fine.  All of a sudden, the whole thing seemed to crash and I started getting this error:

> The web site you are accessing has
>   experienced an unexpected error.
>   Please contact the website
>   administrator.
>
> The following information is meant for
>   the website developer for debugging
>   purposes. Error Occurred While
>   Processing Request A License Exception
>   has been thrown. You tried to access
>   the developer edition from a
>   disallowed IP (xx.xxx.xxx.xx). The
>   developer edition can only be accessed
>   from 127.0.0.1 and two additional IP
>   addresses. The additional IP addresses
>   are: xx.xx.xxx.xxx,xxx.xxx.x.xx

(I removed the IP addresses)

Obviously, it looks like a licensing issue, but why would this happen all of a sudden?  I saw issues where the server would revert to developer edition after 30 days, but I believe the server has been running much longer than that.

Also, I don't even know where to change the version!  I think I need to input my serial number for the product, but I have no idea where to do that.

I can see in the admin interface under the settings summary that the Edition is "Developer", and the Serial Number field is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see in the admin interface under
>   the settings summary that the Edition
>   is "Developer", and the Serial Number
>   field is blank

That's where you enter your valid Standard or Enterprise license code.

As for why it might have reverted to developer mode - have you had any problems lately and had to restore any of the configuration xml files? Alternatively, as Clint suggests, possibly your website was behind a proxy and therefore all requests appeared to be coming from one IP address. (That would be a license violation, by the way, so don't fix the problem by setting up a proxy - lol).

Comment: Its not really a field, so much as a label.  Its not editable.

Comment: I don't think any Cold Fusion configuration files or even applications have been touched recently.  Maybe some networks settings changed.

Comment: ColdFusion 7 had an issue where if the server was unexpectedly rebooted or the ColdFusion service was killed or otherwise not shut down properly, that on occasion, it would "lose" the serial number and revert back to "developer/trial" mode.  Re-entering the serial number through the administrator corrects the immediate problem.  We still have a couple of CF7 servers in production and this comes up every year or so on one of them.  No issues like this with 8 or 9 though that we've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing more about your configuration and application architecture, it's hard to say why it ran for longer than 30 days w/o any issue. It's possible the app was actually used by some kind of proxy, or even other app tier.

Regardless, if the edition is indeed Developer and there is no license key entered, it's going to restricted in the manner you described: only accessible from the IP address on which the server is bound (listening) and 2 other addresses.

If you have a license key, you can enter it in the administrator interface, typically found at /CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm (if installed "normally"). Load the admin interface, click "System Information" (top, main frame) and then input your license key in the field labeled "New License" and click "Submit Changes."

Comment: Ah OK, I see the area for the license key now.  Pretty unintuitive if you ask me!

Comment: Usually the license key is entered at installation, so it's generally not something you need to access frequently in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the license issue was something temporary?  I restarted the windows service for Cold Fusion and it seems like it fixed the issue.

I have a question here about how to start/restart Cold Fusion: [How do you start ColdFusion MX 7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/31529/how-do-you-start-cold-fusion-mx7/31610#31610).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much of an answer for you other than:

1. Make sure you are using JRE v1.5x
2. Upgrade to the latest version of JRE v1.6.0_14

We are having this happen frequently as well, running version Coldfusion Standard (v8,0,1,195765).  We are running on Java 1.6.0_04.

We've determined this is either a load issue or an issue with the JRE.  We noticed some error logs "too many open files" or something similar in our cfserver.log file.

In addition, we found some articles that recommended upgrading the JRE as earlier versions of 1.6 have issues closing connections.

http://corfield.org/blog/index.cfm/do/blog.entry/entry/Java_6_and_ColdFusion_8

Comment: For ColdFusion 7 (from the original post), the latest JRE supported is 1.4.2_17 and it does not support the 1.6 versions (ColdFusion 8 does, however, as you mentioned).  Just an FYI in case someone thinks they can run 1.6 editions on ColdFusion 7... not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this same issue, as a note it is two IP addresses including accessing it from 127.0.0.1.

It is designed so that a web developer can show their work, from their workstation to another party on their own screen, for accessibility testing or similar.

What can happen in situations like this is that if your PC gets an IP address via DHCP, the lease expires and you connect again (with a different IP address this time) this will use up both of your "IP addresses". THe next person to connect will get the message in your question.

For developer instances, if this occurs you should simply restart the coldfusion instance. I normally saw this occur on laptops that were put into hibernation in the office, the developer takes them home and connects to their home wireless, does some work, then for instance comes back into the office, or to another one of the office locations, gets another different IP address and are then unable to browse their site.